# Stop while loop after using cin

Tags: c++

I can't catch the logic of the while loop. Checked many websites and didn't find the right answer.

I tried to use while loop after cin and it shows infinite output. Also tried to use if {break;} but it showed me only one output. Here is the code.

```
cout << "How many chambers did you find? Enter a positive number: ";
cin >> chambers;

while (chambers ){
    chambers = chambers + 1;
    boxes = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    cout << "In chamber number " << chambers << " you found " << boxes << " boxes of gold!" << endl;
}
```

If input 6 output should be:

```
In chamber number 1 you found 8 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 2 you found 50 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 3 you found 74 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 4 you found 59 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 5 you found 31 boxes of gold!
In chamber number 6 you found 73 boxes of gold!
```

How can I stop at 6 if input is 6? What if I input 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the loop control variable `chambers` correctly.

In a while loop, `0 is false`, and `!=0 is true`. Therefore `while(chambers)` will be true for all values of `chambers` except `0`. This is the reason for infinite loop.

You can declare another variable for controlling the loop.

The sample code will be

```
cout << "How many chambers did you find? Enter a positive number: ";
cin >> chambers;

int i = 1
while (i<=chambers ){
    boxes = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    cout << "In chamber number " << i << " you found "
    << boxes << " boxes of gold!" << endl;
    i++;

}
```

Here `i` will be used to control the loop and give the expected out.

Answer (score 0):

In a while loop the result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
You are entering a positive number and increment it by one in the loop which makes a infinite output

```
cout << "How many chambers did you find? Enter a positive number: ";
cin >> chambers;
c = 0;
while (chambers ){
      chambers = chambers - 1;
      boxes = (rand() % 100) + 1;
      cout << "In chamber number " << ++c << " you found "<< boxes << " boxes of gold!" << endl;
}
```